# ASP.Core 5 MVC Session Lost after redirecting application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Everything works fine and the session keeps it Session Id and data.  Then I redirect a user to payment page. After successful payment the user is redirected back to my site

The problem is my sessions lost after redirecting to my application.

How can i fix it?

Thanks

> ```
>    //Redirection code
> ```

HttpContext.Response.Redirect(IyziGo.PaymentPageUrl,false);

> ```
>   //Main Configuration
> ```

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();


            services.AddSession(options =>
            {

                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;

            });

            services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = new MyTransparentJsonNamingPolicy();
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            /*if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }*/
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=startApp}");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
```

Comment: could you check the return url domain name from payment gateway is the same domain name when you redirected to payment gateway, also is your site running under load balancer then you should have sticky sessions the reason being is return url may be hitting difference instance,

Comment: I'am testing my app in my local computer via Visual Studio 2019.  Return url domain name from payment gateway is the same domain name

Comment: what makes you think "The problem is my sessions lost after redirecting to my application."

Comment: What do you you mean?

Comment: sorry! sort of understanding the context of "session". when you say session lost, that means user logged in session dropped and being force to login or from payment provider   redirect it does not reach  localhost?

Comment: in fact the problem is simple. I have a web application (asp.net core). I have session values of course. For payment i 'm redirecting user to payment web site. After payment completed , payment site callback my web app. I put a breakpoint to my code at this moment. The problem is my Session list is empty! I think i have to configure my app for this callback but how?

Comment: well you could try with true, `HttpContext.Response.Redirect(IyziGo.PaymentPageUrl,true);`, I wonder after redirecting payment gateway whether you have any code which runs to clear session data?

Comment: No. not working